# Why is this JQuery $.post() call against a Hapi server running on localhost failing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a nodejs server running on localhost that's using the Hapi framework. Front end is just basic jquery stuff.

I'm just trying to get a post request working to the backend, with some json data in the payload. The backend just checks some of the data, and returns whether or not the answers a user selected are correct.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formSubmitButton").click(function() {
        var name = $("nameEntry").val();
        var math = $("input:radio[name = 'mathAnswer']:checked").val();
        var sendObj = {
            firstName: name,
            number: math
        };
        console.log(sendObj);
        var jsonSend = JSON.stringify(sendObj);

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })

        $.post({url: 'http://localhost:8080/', jsonSend, success: function(result){
            console.log('success?');
            $("#resultDiv").html(result)
        }}).fail(function(response) {
            console.log('FAILURE');
            console.log(response);
        });
    })
})
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form1">
<label>What is the first name linked to your account (avild):
     <input type="text" name="nameEntry" id="nameEntry">
</label>
<label>What is 2 + 2?
    <input type="radio" id='answer1' name="mathAnswer" value="2">
    <label for='answer1'>2</label>
    <input type="radio" id='answer2' name="mathAnswer" value="3">
    <label for='answer2'>3</label>
    <input type="radio" id='answer3' name="mathAnswer" value="4">
    <label for='answer3'>4</label>
</label>
</form>
<button type="button" id="formSubmitButton">Send</button>
```

Hapi Route:

```
{
    method: 'POST',  // Which HTTP method to use
    path:'/', // The path (servername/path)
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        console.log("WE GOT SOMETHING BOYS: ");
        console.log(request.payload);
        var response = controller.checkAnswers(request);
        reply(response);
    }
},
```

Hapi controller:

```
checkAnswers: function(request) {
    try {
        var name = request.payload.firstName;
        var num = request.payload.number;
        var correctAnswers = 0
        if(name.toLowerCase() === answers[0].answer) {
            correctAnswers++;
        }
        if (num === answers[1].answer) {
            correctAnswers++;
        }
        var returnObj = {
            correctAnswers: correctAnswers
        }
        return returnObj;
    } catch(e) {
        return e
    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, what happens is that the JQuery fails, and the log inside the failure callback just gives the standard ajax error block, with a status of 404 and a statusText of 'error'

EDIT 2: And here's the server connection setup

```
server.connection({ port: 8080, host: "localhost", routes: {cors: true}})
```

Comment: How does it fail? Are there any errors ?

Comment: So what's the problem? What's the error?

Comment: Added, forgot I didn't mention it before the code blocks.

Comment: Where is your button ? formSubmitButton how do you submit?

Comment: What's on the server side?

Comment: @headmax Added that, forgot it's currently outside form tag

Comment: @DaveNewton The rest of the server code is just essentially the Hapi boiler plate stuff- the route I posted is the route the jquery request is being made against, and the controller is what the 'handler' block fo the route does for that particular route.

Comment: I think you did a bad configuration about "server.js" the server side Hapi look you got different IP domain ...

Comment: @headmax Added the server connection setup

Comment: try server.connection({ port: 8080, host: "localhost", routes: {cors: true}}); if you didn't set a var localhost = "localhost";

Comment: @headmax Sorry, that was just a typo. Converting from what was in the default.json

Comment: The error on the server. But my bad, you don't have a route configured for what you're hitting/

Comment: @Ajv2324 no problem :)

Comment: Sorry for this question but to be sure, can you start the server and this server is Listening? and did you configured your route for the post ajax you wrote?

Comment: Yes, the server is running. The endpoint works with just a vanilla javascript XMLHttpRequest, and with an angular request, but I can't get it to work in jquery.

Comment: did you install jquery as a module inside angular, or just using a cdn lib or local lib?

Comment: @headmax They are two separate projects- I was comparing solutions to see which framework would work best. But I installed it via the lib.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I found was to not use $.post() at all, but rather $.ajax(). Why this may be, I'm not sure. Perhaps using $.post() against a hard url like localhost doesn't work without some additonal setup?

Here is my current solution:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        data: jsonSend,
        type: 'post',
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('Status: ' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ', status text: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log('Success');
            console.log(result);
            $('#resultDiv').html(result);
        }
});
```